# Flutter Google Sign In error after canceling Choose an account pop-up

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

After clicking sign in, choose an account pop comes up but if the user pressed back or outside of the pop-up it throws an error.

**Error -**

[image]

**Sign in class -**

```
class GoogleSignInProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  GoogleSignInAccount? _user;

  GoogleSignInAccount get user => _user!;

  Future googleLogin() async {
    await googleSignIn.signOut();
    final googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();

    if (googleUser == null) return;
    _user = googleUser;

    final googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

    final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken, idToken: googleAuth.idToken);

    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**Sign out button -**

```
TextButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                final googleCurrentUser = GoogleSignIn().currentUser;

                if (googleCurrentUser != null) {
                  await GoogleSignIn().disconnect();
                }
                FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: const Text(
                'Yes',
                style: TextStyle(color: primaryColor),
              ))
```

Comment: and what's your question? If the user cancels the Auth process, then yes, that's the expected behavior of the library.

Comment: but the app gets stuck once that happens, is there a way to handle ths?

Comment: As it is a exception you can add the try catch block so that you can catch it there it self and show if it is cancelled.

Comment: you will get the error in the exception itself

Comment: I tried wrapping everything in sign in class with a try-catch but still, I'm getting the same exception

Comment: @Mariano Zorrilla I think you're right, cause the app doesn't seem to get stuck on an actual device.

Answer (score 1):

This only happens in debugging, in release this won't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `if (googleUser == null) return;` try using `if (googleUser == null) return null;`.

Here is my sign in method;

```
Future<UserCredential?> signInWithGoogle() async {
  final _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  await _googleSignIn.disconnect().catchError((e, stack) {
    print(e);
  });
    
    final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();

    // handling the exception when cancel sign in
    if (googleUser == null) return null;

    // Obtain the auth details from the request
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication? googleAuth =
        await googleUser.authentication;

    // Create a new credential
    final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleAuth?.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth?.idToken,
    );
    return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
}
```

The sign out method;

```
Future signOut() async {
  var result = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  return result;
}
```